# a simple C++11 regex that throws regex_error while searching

Tags: regex, c++11

I'm using VS2015 community, why the code below throws `std::regex_error` at a specific length of string on my computer.

```
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    try {
        std::string subject(497, '-');
        std::regex  pattern("(.)+");
        bool match = std::regex_search(subject, pattern);
        std::cout << std::boolalpha << match << std::endl;
    }
    catch(const std::regex_error& e) {
        std::cerr << "1: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    try {
        std::string subject(498, '-');
        std::regex  pattern("(.)+");
        bool match = std::regex_search(subject, pattern);
        std::cout << std::boolalpha << match << std::endl;
    }
    catch(const std::regex_error& e) {
        std::cerr << "2: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
true
2: regex_error(error_stack): There was insufficient memory to determine whether the regular expression could match the specified character sequence.
```

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe your regex is too ambiguous. You should try to use `"[-]+"`

Comment: @LingboTang what does a single dash character in brackets mean?

Comment: It means you should only capture the character `"-"`

Comment: @alfC it's true. before this, I didn't know that regex_search throw exceptions. thanks

Comment: @LingboTang that is not what I wanted. By default, `std::regex` uses ECMAScript syntax, and I want to match strings that contains any characters (include `\r`) but `\n` in a `\n`-separated subject, so I write down like this: `((.|\r)*)\n`, then it crashes, but not every time.

Comment: I think '(.)' means capturing group. Please try using non-capturing group there.

Comment: Note that your code works with gcc: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6b0e3f2913d744ae

Comment: Also, this doesn't happen with boost::regex, it's father. It could be MS is behind the eight ball here and won't fix it.

Answer (score 1):

It causes `error_stack` even when using cluster group there `(?:.)+`

I can tell you how to curtail this exception if you want.
And I can tell you what is causing it too.

Use `regex.h` as a reference..

**First**, you'll notice these defines near the top

```
#ifndef _REGEX_MAX_COMPLEXITY_COUNT
  #define _REGEX_MAX_COMPLEXITY_COUNT   10000000L   /* set to 0 to disable */
 #endif /* _REGEX_MAX_COMPLEXITY_COUNT */


#ifndef _REGEX_MAX_STACK_COUNT
  #ifdef _WIN64
   #define _REGEX_MAX_STACK_COUNT   600L    /* set to 0 to disable */
  #else /* _WIN64 */
   #define _REGEX_MAX_STACK_COUNT   1000L   /* set to 0 to disable */
  #endif /* _WIN64 */
#endif /* _REGEX_MAX_STACK_COUNT */
```

To disable either complexity or max stack, at compile time put the definition
you'd like *before* the include file `<regex>`.

For example, set to 0 to disable these protections.
For your test, we can set the stack to 200,000 like this

```
#define _REGEX_MAX_STACK_COUNT 200000
#include <regex>
```

This now will actually not throw an exception now for your example.

**Second**, what causes this in the code.

I just did a glance with a debug session, and found out a general cause.

It all comes in the _Matcher class.

Inside `_Match_pat()` it firsts *decrements* _Max_stack_count,
before exiting it *increments* _Max_stack_count.

`_Max_stack_count` gets set when _Matcher is instantiated.

> template<>class _Matcher
>     {   // provides ways to match a regular expression to a text sequence
>
> ```
>   _Max_stack_count = _REGEX_MAX_STACK_COUNT;
> ```
>
> }

The recursion comes from `_Match_pat()` being called recursively by either
`_Do_if()` and `_Do_rep()` which are initially called from `_Match_pat()`

And the behavior comes mainly from *open ended quantified groups* (capture or cluster) that can match many, many times.

In your case, its `(.)+`
Unusually though, all this is doing is matching a character and putting it
in the capture group 1, but appending it to group 0.

In my opinion, the closure should register a increment of the stack count available
(*pop*), but instead the recursion is being used as a crutch to support
other states that would have to be duplicated to take account of this.

Anyway, you can set breakpoints and try it out for yourself.

Below are the code segments of interest.

```
    bool _Matcher<>::_Match_pat(_Node_base *_Nx)
    {
        if (0 < _Max_stack_count && --_Max_stack_count <= 0)
            _Xregex_error(regex_constants::error_stack);
        while (_Nx != 0)
        {

            case _N_if:
                if (!_Do_if((_Node_if *)_Nx))
                    _Failed = true;
                _Nx = 0;
                break;

            case _N_endif:
                break;

            case _N_rep:
                if (!_Do_rep((_Node_rep *)_Nx,
                    (_Nx->_Flags & _Fl_greedy) != 0, 0))
                    _Failed = true;
                _Nx = 0;
                break;

            case _N_end_rep:
                {   // return at end of loop
                _Node_rep *_Nr = ((_Node_end_rep *)_Nx)->_Begin_rep;
                _Loop_vals_t *_Psav = &_Loop_vals[_Nr->_Loop_number];

                if (_Nr->_Simple_loop == 0 && !_Do_rep(_Nr,
                    (_Nr->_Flags & _Fl_greedy) != 0, _Psav->_Loop_idx))
                    _Failed = true; // recurse only if loop contains if/do
                _Nx = 0;
                break;
                }


        }
        if (0 < _Max_stack_count)
        ++_Max_stack_count;
    }


    bool _Matcher<>::_Do_rep0()
    {   // apply repetition to loop with no nested if/do

        if (!_Match_pat(_Node->_Next))      // Several of these
    }

    bool _Matcher<>::_Do_if()
    {   // apply if node
        if (_Match_pat(_Node->_Next)) // try to match this branch
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Sometimes, I just get a bit angry with c++.

Comment: @user3628322 - Yeah it's tough. Note that you can put `_REGEX_MAX_STACK_COUNT=<number>` in your project defines.