# std::regex_match provokes a stack overflow

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

The following code (win10, target plateform version = 10.0.17134.0, platform toolset = Visual Studio 2015 (v140) in latest update of visual studio 2019 pro, debug x64) :

```
#include <iostream>
//#define _REGEX_MAX_STACK_COUNT 0;
#include <regex>

int main()
{
    int stack_reg = _REGEX_MAX_STACK_COUNT ;

    std::string nok("FDFDFD...FDFD"); // concatenation of "FD" 298 times
    std::string ok( "FDDFFD...FD"); // concatenation of "FD" 297 times
    auto regex(std::regex("([FI]D){1,}"));

    bool res_ok = std::regex_match(ok, regex);
    bool res_nok = std::regex_match(nok, regex); // triggers the exception
    
    return 0;
}
```

triggers the following exception :

[image]

inside `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\xmemory0` when line `bool res_nok = std::regex_match(nok, regex); // triggers the exception` is trying to be executed.

Setting `_REGEX_MAX_STACK_COUNT`  to 200000 or even to 0 (no limit) keeps triggering the same exception.

I tried to apply solution from

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42913977/1581875

but I have no "regex.h" in my include paths so that I can only include `<regex>`.

(Context : the code is one `case` from thousands in a `switch...case` parsing a huge programming language script, so that I would ideally like to do the very same regex with the very same matching pattern in a different way. The problem is that installing boost is not an option for me.)

Comment: First of all, it must be `regex(std::regex("(?:[FI]D)+"))`. I also think you need to compile the project with Release option, not Debug.

Comment: I must compile with Release option ? How can I debug it then ? Also, `regex(std::regex("(?:[FI]D)+"))` did not help.

Comment: I have tried in my Visual Studion 2019, and it works fine, even with your regex.

Comment: Оh ... Ok. Will see. Again : why must it be in release ?

Comment: Debug mode involves additional computational overhead, it has to keep a lot of match information that is not necessary to keep in Release mode.